# Can OData API, written in .Net Core, serve response in a streaming or chunking fashion?

Tags: c#, odata, streaming

I have an OData API which fetches huge amount of data but fails to serve the response in one go as the pods have limited resources. Is there a way, where I can start sending data in chunks, something like server-side paging?
Is there something out of the box, available to achieve so?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend chunking on the client, as in, having the client retrieve x amount of records at a time.

First Chunk:

```
$top=100&$skip=0
```

Second Chunk:

```
$top=100&$skip=100
```

etc...

Comment: I am looking for someway of introducing streaming at the API end, where if user gets a new data points for the query, response is sent in stream